# Copied WordPress site now "blank"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just copied a site over to a new developmental subdomain for some changes. The copy went fine. I used rsync and all files are in place. I dumped the db contents and loaded them up.

Additionally I modified the wp-config.php so that it would have:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.dev.newdomain.tld');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.dev.newdomain.tld');
// Just trying to catch any error info:
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Posts, plugins, users, etc. all show up just fine on the wp admin interface, however **NO** content is being displayed on the front end.

If I modify an article from the wp admin, it edits just fine, however when I attempt to view a post I get the following in my browser:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /path-to-article/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

And the following in my apache error.log:

```
[Tue Feb 05 05:50:07 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/dev.domain.tld/path-to-post
[Tue Feb 05 05:50:07 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/dev.domain.tld/missing.html
```

This part leads me to believe that perhaps it is something going on with apache's .htaccess, however it seems to look okay:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And yes, I have disabled all plugins to see if there could be something going on there. Further, changing the theme to the default "Twenty Twelve" also does not help.

Additionally when looking at the generated page source, there is simply no content within the html.

All I see is a singular access in the access log for the web browser to the root / site resource with NO accompanying other resources (files, images, etc.)

What could be going on here as I am seemingly at an impasse with no errors within the logs whatsoever?

Comment: Has the new server enabled `mod_rewrite.c` ?

Comment: isn't there a few options wp_options table that includes urls that may need to be changed? appreciate you've set the urls in the config.php but still no harm in checking/trying.

Comment: @DainisAbols yes, it has it enabled.

Comment: @TheCellarRoom I have the [Search and Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) prior to posting this to no avail. I sanity checked it by inserting the WP_HOME & WP_SITEURL vars into the config.

Comment: i would try copying the finals again, could easily be something that failed, try it without any plugins first, I'm thinking a caching plugin perhaps.

Comment: Unfortunately everything is fine as far as copying goes. I thought that as well re: caching, but clearing cache did not help.  What I personally think is that this is some kind of an apache problem and that the requests are not getting to WP on the front end properly... BUT I cannot find anything beyond what I've shown above to lead me to that as things "look right."

Comment: maybe this would be better over at the wordpress.stackexchange site or on the WordPress support forums instead?

Answer (score -1):

Check your database. Wordpress stores many URLs as absolute URLs, so that's why you might have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as you can see above in the previous remark to @TheCellarRoom, this was already addressed.